# DateTime parse error, timezone not found, and rounding time

Tags: php, datetime

The following script returns the following error.

```
foreach($data[key($data)] as $index=>$row) {
    $dt = new \DateTime($row['time']);
    $dt->setTimeZone($o->dateTimeZone);
    //...
}
```

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (2018-07-10T17:52:33.931841554Z) at position 0 (2): The timezone could
>   not be found in the database (0)

Is the error caused by `2018-07-10T17:52:33.931841554Z` having to many digits?  If so, how should I round it to less digits so it doesn't cause an error?  Or is it caused by something else?

Comment: remove the backspace from \DateTime($row['time']);

Comment: @MohitKumar How is that supposed to solve this issue?

Comment: The microseconds are messing it up. PHP can only parse microseconds up to 6 digits, and you have 9. ([src, found in comments](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#121431)). You'll have to either use a different DateTime library, or find a way to either remove the microseconds or reduce the precision.

Comment: @aynber  Seems like reducing the precision would be easier (i.e. less change or resulting in other issues) than changing libraries.  Any recommended approach?

Comment: The constructor processes up to 8 microsecond digits, but the instance will keep only 6, rounding the last digit. This is, unfortunately, no documented on php.net

Comment: For some reasons PHP will parse first six characters from `.931841554Z` as the milliseconds and rest it tries to parse as timezone.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of a hack, but this is what I ended up doing.

```
foreach($data[key($data)] as $index=>$row) {
    if($fraction=substr ($row['time'],19,-1)) {
        $row['time']=substr($row['time'],0,19).substr($fraction,0,9).substr($row['time'], -1);
    }
    $dt = new \DateTime($row['time']);
    $dt->setTimeZone($o->dateTimeZone);
    //...
}
```